# Submit button calling wrong submit handler

Tags: forms

I have a form with 3 different "Submit" buttons, and I want each of them to map to a particular Submit handler.

I have included these items using the following, generic, pattern:

```
                    array(
                        '#prefix' => '<td>',
                        '#suffix' => '</td>',
                        '#type' => 'submit',
                        '#value' => 'Update',
                        '#submit' => array('user_profile_details_edit_phone_submit')
                    )
```

But, every time I click the "Submit" button, the incorrect function is called. The function that IS called is the LAST function I add to a submit handler in this way.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If the button labels are all the same that would make sense

Comment: By "label" do you mean whatever is in "#value"? Edit: Wow, that was it. Why the heck can't I have more than one button with the same name?

Comment: Yes sorry, the submit value. It's because Drupal uses the  value to decipher which button was clicked. I wonder does setting a specific `#name` for each button fix it?

Comment: That did it! Thanks, Clive. Want to move your response to an answer, and I'll accept/upvote it? Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: No worries, I thought it sounded familiar :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal uses the name and value of submit buttons to identify which was pressed, and subsequently which submit handlers to run. If the names and values of all three buttons are the same, the FAPI will only be able to use one of them (in this case the last one).

To fix it you can assign a unique `#name` property to each of the buttons.